# How to read data from Slave DB if Master has not replicated data to slave.

Tags: architecture, scalability, high-availability

Lets say we have below requirement: (we have only 1 master and 1 slave)

User opens first page :  enters username , then he presses submit button. Request goes to app server then write/update this username to Master DB . Now when we return success callback from Master, page navigates to page 2. But we have to show details (from Read/Slave DB) on page 2 for this username but lets assume Master has not replicated the data to Slave .So how to handle this scenario:

1. We will check if data is not available in Slave then we can read from Master but again load will be increased on Master.
2. We will check if data is not available in Slave, we will wait for sometime and again we hit Slave server but in this case user will have to wait to load page2.

My question is what other approaches or design solution we can use to get data on page 2 without wait and increasing load.

Comment: How many users do you expect to access your web application. If its not in millions, i think the replication happens pretty fast and you can choose to wait to read from slave db.  What protocol are you using for replicating the data between db ( and which db btw).  What other things is Master DB doing apart from storing the user info. Because if you hit all your read requests to slave, then you might end up loading slave machine as its handling adding the new data as well as reads. Instead would you want to load distribute your requests between the two ?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution strategy should be dependent on the synchronization interval between Master and Slave.

1. If synchronization interval is less, then probability of entity getting replicated in Slave is higher, in which case wait for few seconds and hit slave again.
2. If synchronization interval is higher (because of business need or     certain other reasons) then probability of entity getting replicated in Slave is less, hence you should hit Master directly only in this scenario. In remaining other scenarios or pages, since you are assured that replication is completed, you may hit slave DB.

Answer (score 0):

The case is typical read-write consistency questions. Choose A or C:

1. Async replication. Only read or write on master node, not slave node. (node is data partition unit, each machine take numbers of master nodes and slave nodes), when one machine down, then trigger node rebalance.
2. Sync replication. Return success when all or most return success. (NWR or Paxos)

Our distributed nosql database choose availability not consistency by async replicate data. We only read-write on master data partition.

Problem is when one machine down, all the master partition in the machine which had the un-sended out data couldn't be read by user until the machine back and re-send the data to replicas.

Same data center data replication latency is less than 1ms, which means when machine down, before the machine up, there's 1ms data couldn't be retrieved. Now this could be accepted for our most business requirement.

For different data center we choose multiple clusters (master cluster, slave cluster).